# HowTo run a ShellScript in PHP in loop

Tags: php, bash, shell, loops, infinite

I have a shell script which is excecuted in a php file to get the temperature.

```
<?php 
  $output = shell_exec('sh temperature.sh');
  echo "<pre>$output&deg;C</pre>";
?>
```

Right now it is only excecuted once.
How do I need to change the php file so the Value is always up to date?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping.asp see while/for loop here first. It'll give you good idea on changing your PHP code

Comment: @ArunSangal php loop has nothing to do with his question

Answer (score 1):

`PHP` is a server side language. that means that when its loaded, its done. 
if you want to update it always, you should use ajax calls for that.

```
var interval = 1000; // 1 second
function doAjax() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'get_what_you_want.php',
        data: {},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
                $('body').text(data) // or put it on your page    
        },
        complete: function (data) {
                // Schedule the next
                setTimeout(doAjax, interval);
        }
    });
}
setTimeout(doAjax, interval);
```